# TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

※Sorry My English skills are low, so if you can't understand, free to ask. 
I'm developing a media with Nuxt
I use API that made by Rails stored in a data of article  and display in Nuxt.
In development environment, Data is displayed normally, but In production environment, I caught an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

It's source code

```
<div class="contents-header">  
  <h1>{{posts.title}}</h1>  
</div>  

export default {   

head(){  
  return{  
    title: this.posts.title,  
    meta:[{ hid: 'title', name: 'title', content: this.posts.title }]
  }  

async asyncData({app,params,error}) {  
  const {id} = params;  
  const response  = await axios.get(`https://hogehoge.com/api/v1/posts/${id}`)  
  .catch(err=> {  
  error({  
    statusCode: err.response.status,  
    message: err.response.data.message,  
  });  
  return err.response;  
  });  
  const posts = JSON.parse(response.data)  
  return {posts};  
},  
}
```

Comment: What line of code?

Comment: this→<h1>{{posts.title}}</h1>

Comment: check this plz `${this.posts.title}`

Comment: @RyosukeAono , I have added an answer but you should formatting your code. I haven't a clue what is going on in your code with such absent of formatting.

Comment: @ShahabKhan Where ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your `data` (or `props`) property `posts` because `posts` doesn't exist in scope of vue component:

```
export default {  
    data(){
        posts: [],
    }
}
```

And later in the methods of code you can set `posts` array like this:

```
this.posts = response.data;
```

Comment: I caught the error 「Cannot set property 'posts' of undefined」...